# Encoded QR and Aztec barcodes contain blur/dither

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, zxing, zxingobjc

I'm generating QR and Aztec barcodes in an iOS application using the latest version (3.2.1) of the [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) library. I'm doing so using code identical to the library's "Encoding" example, i.e:

```
NSError *error = nil;
ZXMultiFormatWriter *writer = [ZXMultiFormatWriter writer];
ZXBitMatrix* result = [writer encode:@"A string to encode"
                              format:kBarcodeFormatQRCode
                               width:200
                              height:200
                               error:&error];

CGImageRef imageRef = [[ZXImage imageWithMatrix:result] cgimage];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
myImageView.image = image;
```

However, I see that the barcode which is rendered in my `UIImageView` using the above code contains some blur/dither when transitioning from a black block to a white block. This is undesirable and could impact scanning speed in an environment where scanning speed is top-priority. Here is an example of the barcode zoomed in to make the problem more apparent:

[image: iOS barcode screenshot zoomed in]

**Question:** Is there anything additional I can do when generating/rendering the barcodes in my iOS application to avoid this blur/dither??

Note that I have specified my `UIImageView`'s Content Mode to be Center ([UIViewContentModeCenter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontentmode/uiviewcontentmodecenter)) so that it doesn't scale the contained image and thus I can't imagine the `UIImageView` causing the blur/dither.

As an aside: I'm using the equivalent `com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0` library in an Android application and I'm *not* seeing the same problem there. See zoomed in screenshot of the barcode below from the Android application:

[image: Android barcode screenshot zoomed in]

Answer (score 0):

After testing this on a couple of other devices (iPhone 5s and iPhone 7) I've come to the realisation that this is an issue specific to the iPhone 6+. Turns out that the "physical" resolution (1080 x 1920 px) of the iPhone 6+ is smaller than the "virtual" resolution (1242 x 2208 px) (see [here](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)) and thus the iPhone 6+ does some downsampling of the display and this is what is causing the blur/dither. Sadly I don't think there is anything that can be done about this... unless anyone has any suggestions??